# How do I convert an svg file from inkscape to geoJson format

Tags: json, svg, d3.js, geojson

I have a map that is generated using inkscape, but I want this in geoJson format. How can I achieve this? I need json format for use in d3.js.

Comment: You need to post the SVG somewhere for better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check how your SVG saves the geography. Parse the related values and convert the numbers to the target format. But parsing and interpretation depend on many factors (which xml elements are used in the SVG, `<path>` vs `<line>`, etc.). And the numbers heavily depend on the scaling of your source SVG.

Here is the very generic answer to your very generic question:

1. Parse the SVG
2. Read the required strings and geo numbers from the parse tree
3. Convert (scale) the numbers to the target format.
4. Write out the target format

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible if the SVG contains enough geo-data to do the conversion. If the coordinates and projection data are embedded somewhere in the SVG XML, then the process that Juve outlined can work.